# Quadratic bound for prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I once found the following problem meant to be solved at high-school level (some olympiad-level exercise, I guess), and I have never been able to prove it using elementary methods. Does anybody know a solution, please?

Show that if $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime (with $p_1 = 2$) then $p_n \leq \frac {n^2 +3n +4} 4$. In a weaker form, show that $p_n = O(n^2)$, but using only *elementary* methods.

(Later edit: I remembered that the original statement had an "over $4$" denominator, making the inequality tighter.)

Comment: In order to prove your result by induction if $f(n)=n^2+3n+4$ we have to prove that there is prime between $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ which still an unsolved problem in number theory (even for simple functions as $f=x^2$), If we use Bertrand's postulate we can conclude that $p_n\leq 2^n$ which is not what we need to prove, so I think that it would be very interesting if there is a solution  at a high-school level

Comment: An extremely minor point: $n^2 + 3n + 4$ is always even, and $p_1 = 2 < 8$, so the inequality can be strict.

Comment: Ah, okay, with that edit, the question becomes much more difficult (and now the question as first posed seems quite easy).

Comment: See my answer to a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1092552/9911. This only has to be changed very slightly, to conclude that $\pi({n^2 + 3n + 4\over4}) > n$.

Comment: @doetoe: I'm not trained in arithmetic; could you elaborate a little bit more on what to do next with $\pi (n)$, please? I don't know how to link it to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexM.: $p_n \leq \frac {n^2 +3n +4} 4$ means exactly that $\pi(\frac {n^2 +3n +4} 4) > n$. This is easy to prove with the bound $\pi(n) \ge \frac23 \frac{n}{\log n}$ given in the answer which holds for $n\ge3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1092552/9911): it can be proved by elementary means (as in [Zagier's beautiful "The first 50 million prime numbers"](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~quine/ANT/The%20Mathematical%20Intelligencer%201977%20Zagier.pdf)) that for $n \ge 3$

$$\pi(n) \ge \frac23 \frac{n}{\log n}$$

where $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes below $x$. The statement that $p_n \leq \frac {n^2 +3n +4} 4$ is equivalent to $\pi\left(\frac {n^2 +3n +4} 4\right) \ge n$. For $n = 1,2$ this can be checked directly, for $n\ge3$ it follows from the above inequality.