# $n$-th prime is less than a polynomial of $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. Is there an elementary way to prove the statement that there exists a polynomial function $P$ such that $$p_n \leq P(n),$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$? (Or, alternatively, for all $n$ from some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ onward?) I know the statement is true, and that $p_n$ "behaves asymptotically like" $n \log n,$ but I'm specifically looking for an elementary proof.

(I'd like to show $\sqrt[n]{p_n} \to 1,$ and since trivially $n \leq p_n,$ the result would follow from the squeeze theorem.)

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1092552/19006) in particular

Comment: By prime number theorem $\log n+\log\log n-1 \leq \frac{p_n}{n} \leq \log n+\log\log n,$ see [here,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) therefore $p_n\le n^2$ for sufficiently large $n.$  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/is-there-a-way-to-show-that-sqrtp-n-n) for more detailed illustrations.

Comment: I was going to answer this but @diracdeltafunk saved me the trouble. You would be best off looking up results showing explicit bounds for $\pi(n)$, the prime counting function. Questions about the size of the the nth prime relative to n are related to $\pi(n).$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2414116/631742). It seems that you can't really avoid a lot of work for this .

Comment: Grimm's conjecture comes close if proven as you can turn it into $p_n\leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1$ as a requirement . Grimm's in unsolved though.